# Page to obtain browser and connection information

Tags: asp.net, javascript, browser, cross-browser

We write software as a service solutions using ASP.NET and C#.

Occasionally a client may have an issue due to a specific browser setting / nuance. Or that they are behind an unknown proxy server. They may also be reporting issues that are actually related to localised bandwidth problems.

We're trying to put together a test page that performs a numbers of checks such as

- Browser type / version
- Screen resolution
- Bandwidth estimate
- Is javascript enabled
- Are they behind a proxy server
- Http compression enabled / disabled

Can anyone suggest any examples of performing these checks and also any other checks that would be useful to make?

We're aiming to send users to this page when they are experiencing problems so it can then email us as much detailed information as possible to help track down the core issue.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you part of the way there:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/detectbrowser.aspx

```
Browser/Version
ActiveX
Javascript
VB Script
Java Applet
```